# Como colocar SSL nesse sistema Websokets PHP

Tags: php, websocket

Criei esse chat em websokets mas nao consigo usar no meu domínio com SSL se alguém puder dar uma ajuda http://rlag.esy.es/, são 2 arquivos de códigos para funcionar 1 executável php e o front-end javascript não consegui encontrar na internet

Estou executando o server em um cloud digital ocean e o website na hospedagem hostinger

Parte do codigo do server

```
$secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
$secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
//hand shaking header
$upgrade  = "HTTPS/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
"Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
"Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
"WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
"WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
"Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
```